# What is this material? Could this be containing asbestos or any other harmful material?

Tags: insulation, construction, asbestos, building, basement-insulation

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

[image]

I have this in my furnace room stuffed above the duct and also on the ceiling if u see one of the picture.
What is this?
Can it be containing something harmful as asbestos or something?
Is it mineral wool or rockwool?

Comment: I doubt it. It's going to be hard for anyone here to answer with certainty based on a photo. The only way to know for sure is to send a sample out for testing.

Comment: It is not doing a good insulating job like that.  Think the only reasin it is there is to stop the ducts from banging when the fan comes on.  Like it is probably is adding extra dust to the room.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be rockwool.

But the stock answer to any "could it contain or be contaminated by asbestos?" question is that you will not ***know*** unless you have it lab tested (or it's a branded asbestos product like Transite® board with the markings remaining legible.) [or, I suppose not to be the case here, a legibly branded/labeled non-asbestos product] Many asbestos products are similar to non-asbestos products in appearance, until someone with the appropriate training looks at it with the right sort of microscope (I looked into "how it's done" once, and it is rather complex.)

As for "any other harmful material" you'd then be looking at a long string of tests for variously unlikely things, and that will get expensive.

Age and location of the house can allow you to infer whether asbestos is unlikely due to the house being too new for when it was largely removed from the market in that area. Other than that, if you have doubts, test (and shop around for a reasonably priced lab - there are some high-priced scammers in the business.)

Comment: I'm not overly on fire to distinguish asbestos from rockwool or fiberglass because rockwool and fiberglass have *their own* health issues due to their own breathable micro-fibers (ask anyone who's worked with fiberglass about ["the itch"](https://peashooter85.tumblr.com/post/98770439860/the-greatest-itching-powder-prank-in-history)... so I would definitely still want to encapsulate it.

Answer (score 0):

The guy that put in that insulating board probably worked for a commercial/industrial boiler installer or service company. That is the same board that is installed between the steel boiler base and the fire brick of the combustion chamber in a dry base boiler. It does not have asbestos in it but the fibers are almost as bad as asbestos and yes it will cause you to itch. Always wear protective equipment when handling including full body coveralls, gloves, face mask and a good respirator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now based on your thoughts, you are pointing towards mineral wool?